# How to turn a string into separate arguments?

Tags: java, string, arguments

I've been looking around to find a way to turn a sentence in the form of a string into separate arguments so that i can do:

```
if(stringhere(args[1]).equalsIgnoreCase("argumenthere")) {
   dosomething();
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the background behind this question? Are you parsing command line arguments? If so, there are *much* better ways.

Comment: No i'm using speech recognition and i'm making an algorithm to tell whether or not i'm speaking to it or something else (which is not simple haha). I used to know a lot more than I do now but I stopped coding for about half a year so i've forgotten a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
String[] arguments= sentence.split(" ");
```

A question, where does the `arguments` variable come from?